# inscrutable rules for disallowing binaries on a new Apple Silicon (Big Sur) machine

Tags: big-sur, code-signing, apple-silicon

EDIT: This problem appears to have been a bug in the Apple code signing mechanism, and has been fixed in the 11.1 Big Sur release candidate. At the moment I write this, you need to enrol in the Apple beta software program to receive this update.

Software versions I used when I encountered this problem, for posterity:

- PyCharm: PC-203.5981.165
- Rust toolchain: 1.50.0-nightly (d274fcf86 2020-12-07)
- Rust IntelliJ plugin: 0.3.136.3514-203
- macOS Big Sur 11.0.1 (20B50)

However, as a matter of academic curiosity, I'm still interested in understanding why this happened. My working hypothesis at the moment is that the codesign metadata was somehow corrupted, but in a way undetected by `codesign -dv`

---

I was able to produce a hello-world terminal app that gets SIGKILLed on launch but works as intended after I either

1. reboot the system, or
2. copy the binary to a new location. (After this, it continues to work if I move it back to the original path.)

However, it will continue to be SIGKILLed if instead of copying I *move* the file. Another interesting property of this binary, while in its unoperational state (let's call it `bad_hello`), is that it crashes `codesign -s - bad_hello` with the error "the codesign_allocate helper tool cannot be found or used", even though `codesign_allocate` is available and `codesign -s -` typically works.

Needless to say, this is quite puzzling and seems like a bug in the Apple code signing system.

That's the long and short of the problem. Now, for more details.

---

I've recently acquired an Apple Silicon device, and have run into a bizarre problem as soon as I started writing code.

I made a "hello world" project in Rust. Building with the Rust toolchain from the command-line gives me a functioning binary.

Now, I clear the build artefacts, open my IntelliJ-based IDE, and ask it to build the same project using the same toolchain. It builds. But, I try to run it, and...

```
cgadski@ChristophersMBP hello % ./hello
zsh: killed     ./hello
```

It gets SIGKILLed instantly.

I put the two files side-by-side. One will be `good_hello` and the other, `bad_hello`.

```
cgadski@ChristophersMBP hello % ./good_hello            
hello.
cgadski@ChristophersMBP hello % ./bad_hello
zsh: killed     ./bad_hello
```

They were built from the same code with the same toolchain with the same options, so I'd expect them to be the same.

```
cgadski@ChristophersMBP hello % diff good_hello bad_hello
[no output here]
```

Indeed, `diff` says they are. `xattr` says they both had no extended attributes, and `mdls` says they only differ in their names and certain timestamps:

```
cgadski@ChristophersMBP hello % diff good_mdls bad_mdls   
1,2c1,2
< _kMDItemDisplayNameWithExtensions      = "good_hello"
< kMDItemContentCreationDate             = 2020-12-14 00:41:15 +0000
---
> _kMDItemDisplayNameWithExtensions      = "bad_hello"
> kMDItemContentCreationDate             = 2020-12-14 00:39:07 +0000
4c4
< kMDItemContentModificationDate         = 2020-12-14 00:41:15 +0000
---
> kMDItemContentModificationDate         = 2020-12-14 00:39:07 +0000
13c13
< kMDItemDateAdded                       = 2020-12-14 00:41:23 +0000
---
> kMDItemDateAdded                       = 2020-12-14 00:40:55 +0000
15c15
< kMDItemDisplayName                     = "good_hello"
---
> kMDItemDisplayName                     = "bad_hello"
17,18c17,18
< kMDItemFSContentChangeDate             = 2020-12-14 00:41:15 +0000
< kMDItemFSCreationDate                  = 2020-12-14 00:41:15 +0000
---
> kMDItemFSContentChangeDate             = 2020-12-14 00:39:07 +0000
> kMDItemFSCreationDate                  = 2020-12-14 00:39:07 +0000
26c26
< kMDItemFSName                          = "good_hello"
---
> kMDItemFSName                          = "bad_hello"
```

`codesign -dv` also returns the same for each binary, with the exception of the `Executable` field. Strange! And every stranger: after I restart the computer, they both work.

```
cgadski@ChristophersMBP hello % ./bad_hello
hello.
cgadski@ChristophersMBP hello % ./good_hello
hello.
```

After learning that code signs sometimes "break" and need to be corrected by "copying the binary and re-signing it", I make a fresh version of `bad_hello` and try it out. Actually, I find something more mysterious: it's enough to just copy the file.

```
cgadski@ChristophersMBP hello % ./bad_hello
zsh: killed     ./bad_carm
cgadski@ChristophersMBP hello % cp bad_hello some_random_new_path
cgadski@ChristophersMBP hello % ./some_random_new_path 
hello.
cgadski@ChristophersMBP hello % mv some_random_new_path bad_hello
cgadski@ChristophersMBP hello % ./bad_hello
hello.
```

My questions are: what could the IDE be doing to break my binary in this way? (It claims to just be invoking the same toolchain command, `cargo build` in this case.) And, what is it about the original `bad_hello` that warrants a SIGKILL?

Comment: What is the version and details of your IDE? Maybe it just needs a patch or bug report, but hard to guess.

Comment: I still have no idea what aspect of `bad_hello` was broken, but I believe we should put this problem at the doorstep of the OS. Luckily, everything is working properly after upgrading to the latest 1.11 release candidate.

Comment: Could be - glad you have it working. Adding build versions for everything really helps people, especially six months or three years from now in addition to people today that might find this and learn a fix they can do.

Answer (score 3):

All binaries run on M1 need to be code signed. It can be an ad-hoc signature, and the first party toolchain will perform the necessary step, but other tools may not.

> the operating system will enforce that any executable must be signed with a valid signature before it’s allowed to run. There isn’t a specific identity requirement for this signature: a simple ad-hoc signature issued locally is sufficient, which includes signatures which are now generated automatically by the linker.

> This new policy doesn’t apply to translated x86 binaries running under Rosetta, nor does it apply to macOS 11 running on Intel platforms.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-big-sur-11-universal-apps-beta-release-notes

You can apply a signature on a binary with `codesign` using `-s` (sign):

```
codesign -s - /path/to/binary
```

You can see whether a binary has a code signature using `-d` (display contents):

```
codesign -dv /path/to/binary
```

The `diff` tool won't display any difference since the files are identical, but the signature will mean the binary runs.

```
$ echo foo > a
$ echo foo > b

$ codesign -dv a
a: code object is not signed at all
$ codesign -dv b
b: code object is not signed at all

$ codesign -s - a
$ codesign -dv a
Executable=/Users/user/a
Identifier=a-f1d2d2f924e986ac86fdf7b36c94bcdf32beec15
Format=generic
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=187 flags=0x2(adhoc) hashes=1+2 location=embedded
Signature=adhoc
Info.plist=not bound
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources=none
Internal requirements count=0 size=12

$ diff a b
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: But isn’t it odd that according to OP, diff says the binaries are identical? Since a code signature modifies the binary.

Comment: Btw, might want to mention the code signature requirement does not apply to Intel binaries run via Rosetta.

Comment: Thanks, we seem to be getting somewhere... but I'm still not quite there yet. Running `codesign -s - bad_hello` in this case returns the error `bad_hello: the codesign_allocate helper tool cannot be found or used`, while doing the same for `good_hello` succeeds silently.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy `diff` won't show anything, added example. Mentioned Intel binaries, thanks

Comment: @Christopher Sounds like you're missing part of the Xcode toolchain, check `xcode-select -p` points to the Developer folder within Xcode or the CLT. (Apparently CLT is fine for macOS builds, just not iOS.)

Comment: @grg I get `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

Comment: @Christopher Does `type codesign_allocate` succeed? There should be one in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Another strange point: `codesign -dv {good,bad}_hello` give the same thing, except for the `Executable=` line.

Comment: Yes, I get `codesign_allocate is /usr/bin/codesign_allocate`. (Also, `codesign -s - good_hello` succeeds.)

Comment: I may need to ask a new question, but I'm now very curious about what's going on with `diff` and code signatures. Do code signatures not actually modify the binary? Would they have different sha hashes?